# Why can't Android Studio building find symbol variable MockPackageManager?

Tags: java, android

Here I want to find longitude and latitude and show it into the xml.

```
package com.example.adeeb.gamecom;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

Button btnShowLocation;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 2;
String mPermission  = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
GPSTracker gps;
TextView location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try
    {

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,mPermission)!= 
         MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] 
              {mPermission},REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V)
        {
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
            location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationtext);
            if(gps.canGetLocation())
            {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                location.setText(latitude+" "+longitude);

            }

            else
            {
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}
Why the compiler can is giving error cannot find symbol variable MockPackageManager. if i use packagemanager the app is not showing longitude and latitude. how can i resolve this?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the errors and messages your are getting, as text. Also, clarify your first statement. What do you mean about "show it into the xml"?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that MockManager is a (deprecated) test class for mocking the package manager behaviors.

I had a similar issue when I changed my Target API to 28. And the below-given code worked well for me.

```
 try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{mPermission},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```